# Append chunks of bytes to a buffer and save the buffer to file

Tags: c#, node.js, buffer, concatenation, corruption

I have a simple c# application that records the screen with ffmpeg and redirects the standardoutput which is sent in chunks to a node.js server, but i am having some trouble with the file getting corrupt.

I have testet the output in c# by saving the chunks to a memorystream and saving it to a file stream.

Here are some c# (using [Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet))

```
while (!theProcess.HasExited)
{
    int count = 0;
    var b = new byte[32768]; // 32k
    while ((count = theProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
    {
        // The chunk to be sent
        byte[] actual = b.Take(count).ToArray();
        // Chuck being sent to node
        clientSocket.Emit("videoChunk", actual);
        if (!ffWorkerIsWorking)
        {
            ffWorker.CancelAsync();
            theProcess.Kill();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the node server

```
var buffer = new Buffer(32768);
var isBufferingDone = false;
var i = 0;
socket.on('videoChunk', function(data) {
    if (!isBufferingDone) {
        var incomingBuffer = new Buffer(data);
        buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, incomingBuffer]);
        i++;
        console.log('Received packages: ' + i);
    }
});

socket.on('cancelVideo', function() {
    isBufferingDone = true;
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('public/test.webm');
    wstream.write(buffer);
    wstream.end
    buffer = new Buffer(32768);
    i = 0;
});
```

So concatenating the buffers as they come in and when it is a cancel request the process stops and the concatenated buffers are written to a file.

The file is corrupt and i dont see why. Anyone care to have a look? Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:**

I ended up fixing this by rewriting the javascript to this:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(32768);
var isBufferingDone = false;
var i = 0;
var wstream;

socket.on('videoChunk', function(data) {
    if (i === 0) {
        wstream = fs.createWriteStream('public/'+socket.id+'_video.webm');   
    }
    if (!isBufferingDone) {
        wstream.write(data);
        i++;
        console.log('Received packages: ' + i);
    }
});

socket.on('cancelVideo', function() {
    isBufferingDone = true;
    wstream.end
    fs.unlink('public/'+socket.id+'_video.webm');
    buffer = new Buffer(32768);
    i = 0;
});
```

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: managed to get passed the file corruption but if anyone have something to add to this please do.

Comment: FWIW it's better to stream the chunks as they come in anyway, otherwise someone could upload a huge file and cause your node process to explode.

Comment: That is my end goal but thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your buffering solution is that you're initially concatenating whatever "random" bytes the OS is giving you when you do `new Buffer(32768)` with the actual video data.

Even though buffering in memory is a bad idea, here is how you might fix that solution:

```
var buffer = '';
socket.on('videoChunk', function(data) {
  if (buffer !== null)
    buffer += data;
});

socket.on('cancelVideo', function() {
  fs.writeFile('public/test.webm', buffer, { encoding: 'binary' }, function(err) {
    // Done writing!
  });
  buffer = null;
});
```

That solution assumes that the incoming `data` strings are *binary* strings. If you're sending something other than that, like base64-encoded binary data, then you will need to tweak that example a bit so that `encoding: 'binary'` in `fs.writeFile()` would be `encoding: 'base64'`.

Also, for your streaming solution, you can avoid having to `new Buffer(32768)` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have instead of doing it like this rather gone with somewhat other approach: `var isBufferingDone = false;
 var i = 0;
 var wstream;
 
 socket.on('videoChunk', function(data) {
     if (i === 0) {
            wstream = fs.createWriteStream('public/'+socket.id+'_video.' + videoExt);
     }
        if (!isBufferingDone) {
            wstream.write(data);
            i++;
            if (i === 8) {
                socket.broadcast.emit('video',{videoid:socket.id,videoExt: videoExt});
            }
            console.log('received package (' + i + ')');
        }
 });`